# 2 One Dimensional arrays to 1 Two Dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays like this

```
array x [Firefox,IE,Chrome,Opera]
array y [40,30,25,5]

Required final [[Firefox,40],[IE,30],[Chrome,25],[Opera,5]]
```

I need this in PHP.I think I can run a for loop and do something like this .

```
final23 [0][i] = x[i];
final23 [1][i] = y[i];
```

Is there any better way or built in function in PHP ?

Comment: Worth to mention: Your "I can [..] do something like this"-pseudocode will not result into the structure you want to achieve. You mixed up the both keys (should be `final23[i][0]` instead of `final23[0][i]`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result = array();
$size = max(count($x), count($y));
for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
  $result[] = array(
       isset($x[$i]) ? $x[$i] : null,
       isset($y[$i]) ? $y[$i] : null
  );
}
```

Comment: Stating the obvious would be that if `$y`'s length is smaller than $x this would throw an error.

Comment: I assumed, that one should take care himself, that both arrays are of the same size, but no problem anymore: The corresponding values will be `null` now, if one of both is smaller, than the other. However, the code feels broken anyway, if the sizes doesn't match.

Comment: Yes, I assumed you'd know. But I'd thought I would just throw it out there so that OP wouldn't miss out.

Comment: Yes In my code I will Always have both arrays same size . So there will never be an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = array("Mozzila","IE","Firefox","Opera");
$y = array(40,30,25,5);
$final = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($x as $a){
    $final[] = array($a,$y[$i]);
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Little bit shorter: `foreach ($x as $i => $a) { $final[] = array($a,$y[$i]); }` and so on.

Answer (score -2):

Learn about [Associated array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

```
$arr = new Array("40"=>"FireFox","30"=>"IE","25"=>"Chrome","5"=>"Opera");
```